# Why doesn't PDO execute the whole statement the first time around?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have a DDL script that will create a bunch of tables, and I am using [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1473313/4233593) to clean the database in between tests.

The first time I run this script, it creates all the tables just like it should.

```
CleanMsSQLdb($pdo);

$ddl = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/ddl.sql');

$pdo->exec($ddl);
```

[image]

But for some strange reason, if I try to run the script a second time, I get an error because it didn't drop all the tables like it was supposed to.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 2714 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server] **There is already an object named 'tmpDataRecordSAMPLE' in the database.** (SQLExecDirect[2714] at /build/php7.0-41GaEn/php7.0-7.0.8/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c:247)

[image]

What really disturbs me is that if I simply run the clean script twice in a row, then it drops everything and works fine.

```
CleanMsSQLdb($pdo);
CleanMsSQLdb($pdo);

$ddl = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/ddl.sql');

$pdo->exec($ddl);
```

Why is it not dropping all the tables on the first pass?

I'm not getting any errors when trying to drop tables.

If I run the statement in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, then it drops all the tables as it should on the first pass, so why not from PDO?

---

## About Me

I'm running Ubuntu Linux 16.04.1 with PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 (cli) ( NTS ) connecting to Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3) (KB3072779) - 11.0.6020.0 (X64) using the [Microsoft® ODBC Driver 13 (Preview) for SQL Server®](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50419)

```
$hostname = 'sql.example.com';
$database = 'mydb';
$username = 'db_owner';
$password = 'P@55w0rd';
$driver   = 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server';

$pdo = new PDO("odbc:Driver=$driver;
    Server=$hostname;
    Database=$database",
    $username,
    $password
);
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

## ddl.sql

Sorry for the large data dump, but I couldn't reproduce this will smaller scripts, so there's something curious about these tables in particular.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [tmpData] (
    [date] datetime,
    jpetl_id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE [tmpDataRecord] (
    jpetl_pid int,
    CONSTRAINT fk_tmpDataRecord
        FOREIGN KEY (jpetl_pid)
        REFERENCES [tmpData](jpetl_id),
    [id] tinyint,
    jpetl_id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE [tmpDataRecordSAMPLE] (
    jpetl_pid int,
    CONSTRAINT fk_tmpDataRecordSAMPLE
        FOREIGN KEY (jpetl_pid)
        REFERENCES [tmpDataRecord](jpetl_id),
    [id] tinyint,
    [created] datetime,
    [CONTRACT_TERM] varchar(8),
    [PRICE] decimal(6,3),
    [ABSTRACT] varchar(100),
    jpetl_id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE [tmpDataRecordSAMPLEADMIN_DEP] (
    jpetl_pid int,
    CONSTRAINT fk_tmpDataRecordSAMPLEADMIN_DEP
        FOREIGN KEY (jpetl_pid)
        REFERENCES [tmpDataRecordSAMPLE](jpetl_id),
    [id] bigint,
    [primaryKey] varchar(10),
    [DEP] varchar(10),
    jpetl_id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE [tmpDataRecordSAMPLESUPP_DEP] (
    jpetl_pid int,
    CONSTRAINT fk_tmpDataRecordSAMPLESUPP_DEP
        FOREIGN KEY (jpetl_pid)
        REFERENCES [tmpDataRecordSAMPLE](jpetl_id),
    [id] bigint,
    [primaryKey] varchar(19),
    jpetl_id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE [tmpDataRecordSAMPLESUPP_DEPDEP] (
    jpetl_pid int,
    CONSTRAINT fk_tmpDataRecordSAMPLESUPP_DEPDEP
        FOREIGN KEY (jpetl_pid)
        REFERENCES [tmpDataRecordSAMPLESUPP_DEP](jpetl_id),
    [DEP] varchar(19),
    jpetl_id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE [tmpDataRecordSAMPLETITLE] (
    jpetl_pid int,
    CONSTRAINT fk_tmpDataRecordSAMPLETITLE
        FOREIGN KEY (jpetl_pid)
        REFERENCES [tmpDataRecordSAMPLE](jpetl_id),
    [TITLE] varchar(19),
    jpetl_id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE [tmpDataRecordSAMPLESAMPLE_AUTH] (
    jpetl_pid int,
    CONSTRAINT fk_tmpDataRecordSAMPLESAMPLE_AUTH
        FOREIGN KEY (jpetl_pid)
        REFERENCES [tmpDataRecordSAMPLE](jpetl_id),
    [id] tinyint,
    [FACULTY_NAME] smallint,
    [FACULTY_NAMEfid] smallint,
    [FNAME] varchar(4),
    [MNAME] varchar(100),
    [LNAME] varchar(3),
    [ISSTUDENT] varchar(100),
    [DISPLAY] varchar(2),
    [INITIATION] datetime,
    jpetl_id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE [tmpDataRecordSAMPLESAMPLE_EDITOR] (
    jpetl_pid int,
    CONSTRAINT fk_tmpDataRecordSAMPLESAMPLE_EDITOR
        FOREIGN KEY (jpetl_pid)
        REFERENCES [tmpDataRecordSAMPLE](jpetl_id),
    [id] tinyint,
    [FACULTY_NAME] varchar(100),
    [FNAME] varchar(100),
    [MNAME] varchar(100),
    [LNAME] varchar(100),
    [DISPLAY] varchar(100),
    jpetl_id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE [Data] (
    [date] datetime,
    jpetl_id int  PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE [DataRecord] (
    jpetl_pid int,
    CONSTRAINT fk_DataRecord
        FOREIGN KEY (jpetl_pid)
        REFERENCES [Data](jpetl_id),
    [id] tinyint,
    jpetl_id int  PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE [DataRecordSAMPLE] (
    jpetl_pid int,
    CONSTRAINT fk_DataRecordSAMPLE
        FOREIGN KEY (jpetl_pid)
        REFERENCES [DataRecord](jpetl_id),
    [id] tinyint,
    [created] datetime,
    [CONTRACT_TERM] varchar(8),
    [PRICE] decimal(6,3),
    [ABSTRACT] varchar(100),
    jpetl_id int  PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE [DataRecordSAMPLEADMIN_DEP] (
    jpetl_pid int,
    CONSTRAINT fk_DataRecordSAMPLEADMIN_DEP
        FOREIGN KEY (jpetl_pid)
        REFERENCES [DataRecordSAMPLE](jpetl_id),
    [id] bigint,
    [primaryKey] varchar(10),
    [DEP] varchar(10),
    jpetl_id int  PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE [DataRecordSAMPLESUPP_DEP] (
    jpetl_pid int,
    CONSTRAINT fk_DataRecordSAMPLESUPP_DEP
        FOREIGN KEY (jpetl_pid)
        REFERENCES [DataRecordSAMPLE](jpetl_id),
    [id] bigint,
    [primaryKey] varchar(19),
    jpetl_id int  PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE [DataRecordSAMPLESUPP_DEPDEP] (
    jpetl_pid int,
    CONSTRAINT fk_DataRecordSAMPLESUPP_DEPDEP
        FOREIGN KEY (jpetl_pid)
        REFERENCES [DataRecordSAMPLESUPP_DEP](jpetl_id),
    [DEP] varchar(19),
    jpetl_id int  PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE [DataRecordSAMPLETITLE] (
    jpetl_pid int,
    CONSTRAINT fk_DataRecordSAMPLETITLE
        FOREIGN KEY (jpetl_pid)
        REFERENCES [DataRecordSAMPLE](jpetl_id),
    [TITLE] varchar(19),
    jpetl_id int  PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE [DataRecordSAMPLESAMPLE_AUTH] (
    jpetl_pid int,
    CONSTRAINT fk_DataRecordSAMPLESAMPLE_AUTH
        FOREIGN KEY (jpetl_pid)
        REFERENCES [DataRecordSAMPLE](jpetl_id),
    [id] tinyint,
    [FACULTY_NAME] smallint,
    [FACULTY_NAMEfid] smallint,
    [FNAME] varchar(4),
    [MNAME] varchar(100),
    [LNAME] varchar(3),
    [ISSTUDENT] varchar(100),
    [DISPLAY] varchar(2),
    [INITIATION] datetime,
    jpetl_id int  PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE [DataRecordSAMPLESAMPLE_EDITOR] (
    jpetl_pid int,
    CONSTRAINT fk_DataRecordSAMPLESAMPLE_EDITOR
        FOREIGN KEY (jpetl_pid)
        REFERENCES [DataRecordSAMPLE](jpetl_id),
    [id] tinyint,
    [FACULTY_NAME] varchar(100),
    [FNAME] varchar(100),
    [MNAME] varchar(100),
    [LNAME] varchar(100),
    [DISPLAY] varchar(100),
    jpetl_id int  PRIMARY KEY
);
```

## CleanMsSQLdb

This is pretty much a copy-paste from [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1473313/4233593) only breaking up the batch `GO` statements into multiple `exec`

```
function CleanMsSQLdb(PDO $pdo){
    $sql = "
        /* Drop all non-system stored procs */
        DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128)
        DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)

        SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'P' AND category = 0 ORDER BY [name])

        WHILE @name is not null
        BEGIN
            SELECT @SQL = 'DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[' + RTRIM(@name) +']'
            EXEC (@SQL)
            PRINT 'Dropped Procedure: ' + @name
            SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'P' AND category = 0 AND [name] > @name ORDER BY [name])
        END
    ";
    $pdo->exec($sql);

    $sql = "
        /* Drop all views */
        DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128)
        DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)

        SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'V' AND category = 0 ORDER BY [name])

        WHILE @name IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SELECT @SQL = 'DROP VIEW [dbo].[' + RTRIM(@name) +']'
            EXEC (@SQL)
            PRINT 'Dropped View: ' + @name
            SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'V' AND category = 0 AND [name] > @name ORDER BY [name])
        END
    ";
    $pdo->exec($sql);

    $sql = "
        /* Drop all functions */
        DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128)
        DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)

        SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT') AND category = 0 ORDER BY [name])

        WHILE @name IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SELECT @SQL = 'DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[' + RTRIM(@name) +']'
            EXEC (@SQL)
            PRINT 'Dropped Function: ' + @name
            SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT') AND category = 0 AND [name] > @name ORDER BY [name])
        END
    ";
    $pdo->exec($sql);

    $sql = "
        /* Drop all Foreign Key constraints */
        DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128)
        DECLARE @constraint VARCHAR(254)
        DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)

        SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME)

        WHILE @name is not null
        BEGIN
            SELECT @constraint = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND TABLE_NAME = @name ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME)
            WHILE @constraint IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE [dbo].[' + RTRIM(@name) +'] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + RTRIM(@constraint) +']'
                EXEC (@SQL)
                PRINT 'Dropped FK Constraint: ' + @constraint + ' on ' + @name
                SELECT @constraint = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME <> @constraint AND TABLE_NAME = @name ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME)
            END
        SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME)
        END
    ";
    $pdo->exec($sql);

    $sql = "
        /* Drop all Primary Key constraints */
        DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128)
        DECLARE @constraint VARCHAR(254)
        DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)

        SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME)

        WHILE @name IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SELECT @constraint = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND TABLE_NAME = @name ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME)
            WHILE @constraint is not null
            BEGIN
                SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE [dbo].[' + RTRIM(@name) +'] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + RTRIM(@constraint)+']'
                EXEC (@SQL)
                PRINT 'Dropped PK Constraint: ' + @constraint + ' on ' + @name
                SELECT @constraint = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME <> @constraint AND TABLE_NAME = @name ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME)
            END
        SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME)
        END
    ";
    $pdo->exec($sql);

    $sql = "
        /* Drop all tables */
        DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128)
        DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)

        SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'U' AND category = 0 ORDER BY [name])

        WHILE @name IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SELECT @SQL = 'DROP TABLE [dbo].[' + RTRIM(@name) +']'
            EXEC (@SQL)
            PRINT 'Dropped Table: ' + @name
            SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'U' AND category = 0 AND [name] > @name ORDER BY [name])
        END
    ";
    $pdo->exec($sql);
}
```

Comment: try to loop over results and get the error message as described here: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#multiquery - it should report an error, if there is any (and there should be, during failed cleanup process).

Comment: @YourCommonSense thanks for the input, but I've tried to apply that every way I can, but because none of my statements return a result set, attempting to call `$stmt->fetchAll()` causes error `Invalid cursor state SQLFetchScroll[0]`

Comment: yes of course fetchall makes no sense here. I hoped you would read the explanation part, on returning the results of multiple queries

Comment: @YourCommonSense thank you for your help. After looking through all the result sets for errors, I discovered the problem fixed itself. Turns out it was all those `PRINT` statements interfering. I appreciate you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out all those `PRINT` statements were interfering with the cursor, but only for the foreign key drops.

There are two fixes, either delete all the `PRINT` statements, or [close the cursor](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php).

Using the latter, I changed all the exec lines:

```
$pdo->exec($sql);
```

to query and close cursor:

```
$pdo->query($sql)->closeCursor();
```

## tl;dr

After each one of the batch statements, I looped through the result sets to view the error messages like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
do {
    var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());
} while ($stmt->nextRowset());
```

And I've gotten some curious results. Firstly, I get 3 of these, which makes sense because I have no procs, views, or functions.

```
array(4) {
  [0] =>
  string(5) "00000"
  [1] =>
  int(0)
  [2] =>
  string(24) " ((null)[0] at (null):0)"
  [3] =>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Then I get 16 of these. Of the 18 tables, 16 of them have foreign keys, so this also makes sense. Although, it's curious why I only see the last print statement in the loop (I expect `fk_DataRecord` to be dropped last) repeated for each iteration of the loop. I would expect the print statement to be different for each of the 16 fk_constraints dropped.

```
array(4) {
  [0] =>
  string(5) "01000"
  [1] =>
  int(0)
  [2] =>
  string(186) "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Dropped FK Constraint: fk_DataRecord on Da
taRecord (SQLExecute[0] at /build/php7.0-41GaEn/php7.0-7.0.8/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:256)"
  [3] =>
  string(5) "01000"
}
```

Then I was baffled that the problem didn't exist anymore!

This led me to discover a helpful note in the [execute documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php):

> Note:
>   Some drivers require to close cursor before executing next statement.