# Reset MySQL to default

Tags: mysql, debian, default, reset

I've got several Debian servers with MySQL or MariaDB, and I'm often asked about if it is possible to reset de whole MySQL to its defaults, droping user created ***but not dropping any databases***.

Is that possible?

I used to dump all databases and purging the MySQL/MariaDB installation (apt-get purge)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drop all the tables, stored procedures, triggers, constraints and all the dependencies in one sql statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536350/drop-all-the-tables-stored-procedures-triggers-constraints-and-all-the-depend)

Comment: Although it's similar, in that post they drop all tables, trigers and so on. I don't want to do so. ;)

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I didn´t read it careful enough.